# What do you call the people who drive tourists around a resort in a golf cart?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm creating an original character for a novel, but I'm having trouble finding the exact name of his job. He works in a luxury hotel/timeshare resort, and his job is to drive tourists around the resort and drop them off at their timeshare home in a golf cart. These golf carts (there are SEVERAL) are parked in the front outside of the lobby where doormen and bellhops usually stay under the building's marquee, and after checking in, tourists just hop on and get a free, relaxing ride to their temporary homes. Any help is appreciated.

Example sentence: “What's his job again?”
“Oh, he's a _______ (can be two or more words) at that resort you wanted to go to last summer!”

Comment: A [shuttle driver](http://theranchatlagunabeach.atsondemand.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=512408.viewjobdetail&CID=512408&JID=540097&source=Indeed), perhaps.

Comment: They are often porters. It depends on the resort size. If it's a real highfalutin place, they work for concierge services, part of customer services. [linky](http://www.sandals.com/difference/sandals-club/)

Answer (score 1):

[Golf cart driver](https://www.google.it/search?q=golf%20cart%20driver%20job&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=golf%20cart%20driver%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i60l2.6464j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) is a the expression commonly  used , also as a job title. (See the link)